# Подсчет отрицательных значений переменных php

Tags: php

В php обработчик передаются значения из формы html.
Например, есть

```
$sum = $_POST['q'] + $_POST['w'] + $_POST['e'] +$_POST['r']
```

Пусть q и w будут отрицательными числами.
Можно ли посчитать количество этих отрицательных чисел и вывести их в отдельную переменную? Через if не могу это сделать, чисел много.

Comment: воспользуйтесь foreach

Comment: можно использовать [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) и получить все отрицательные элементы, либо [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-reduce.php) и подсчитать количество отрицательных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$minus = array();
foreach($_POST as $value){
    if (intval($value) < 0) $minus[] = $value;
}
echo count($minus);
```

Comment: если нас только количество интересует, то почему бы не вести подсчет только этого количества, а не всех отрицательных элементов?

Comment: @BOPOH Ну у него написано вот так - Пусть q и w будут отрицательными числами. Можно ли посчитать количество этих отрицательных чисел и вывести их в **отдельную переменную**?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте цикл. Либо сразу по массиву $POST, либо по специально созданному массиву, в котором перечислите индексы переменных из $_POST, которые вам актуальны.

Answer (score 0):

Заведите переменную счетчик и пробегитесь по массиву с помощью `foreach`.Внутри цикла проверяете если значение меньше нуля делаете инкременте счетчику.